# Ingnoring module on certain step

Tags: maven-2

I have multimodule project.

Can I make it somehow work that when calling compile it would ignore a module, but in all other cases include it ?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible with the Maven compiler plugin. Why do you actually need this?

Comment: Some tweak ... :-( long story ...

Comment: I don't understand your need, nor the question. What are "all other cases"? Do you mean the other phases preceding `compile`? Or maybe invoking another phase like `package`? Why do you have a module if you don't want to compile it? Why do you put sources in this module? Can you please clarify?

Comment: in case there are no sources in the module, compile will have nothing to execute. if you have sources, why are they there if not to be compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments, i too do not know why? One possible solution: Make a profile in the parent of the module the you will exclude when compiling.

mvn -Pexclude-profile compile   //will exclude

mvn compile                     //will include

This assume that you do not need any thing else from the module, all other life-cycles are excluded too.